# convert image of a slide to native PowerPoint slide

Tags: image, file, powerpoint, slide

Is there any library that can help me convert an image of a PowerPoint slide to a native PowerPoint slide? There are several online tools but they return an image of the slide on the slide. I would like the slide to have native PowerPoint objects, real charts, real textboxes etc?

Here is an example of an image which I would like to convert:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Highly doubt such a library exists. My guess is you're better off recreating the chart from scratch.

Comment: If your original file format is a vector format, like PDF, EMF or EPS, it might be possible, though in my experience the results are usually disappointing.. If the original is a bitmap (PNG. JPG), then no original objects exist and you would have to run it through an OCR program to even retrieve the text.

Comment: @JohnKorchok very interesting. So converting a PDF to native PPTX is more likely than Image to PPTX. Are there any tools which exist to do this? or is it a custom job?

Comment: PDFElement can export a PDF to PowerPoint. https://pdf.wondershare.com/download-pdfelement-windows.html I'm sure there are other libraries, just Google _PDF to PPTX_.

Comment: PPT to image is like making stew from meat and raw vegetables. Image to PPT is like making meat and raw vegetables from stew. That said, I've heard there are programs that'll convert images of graphs to something that PPT or Excel can use. Perhaps google will turn something up for you. "So converting a PDF to native PPTX is more likely than Image to PPTX?"  Depending on what went into the PDF in the first place, yes. If all that's in it are images, you're faced with stew again, though.